# How can i check if 2 controls overlap eachother on a canvas in WPF?

Tags: wpf, canvas, drag, collision, overlap

I am writing a designer that enables the user to drag controls around the screen.
What would be the best way of detecting if a control is overlapping another control while i am dragging the one control around?

Should i just get the dimensions of the FrameworkElement and keep on checking the dimensions of the other elements?

Thanks.
Eli

Comment: Do you want to know if the bounding rectangles overlap, or the visible areas?  For example, two ellipses might have overlapping bounding rectangles, but the actual ellipses might not even be touching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth FrameworkElement.ActualHeight)  and postion (Canvas.Top, Canvas.Bottom,Canvas.Left, Canvas.Right) of your elements would suffice if they are always rectangular. In that case you can easily calculate if two rectangles overlap. If you elements can be of more complex shapes it gets hairy. I have no idea if I can test for intersection of two Visual instances in WPF.

Maybe we can use [hittesting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx)? With this approach you could at least test if a certain [point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointhittestparameters.aspx) or [geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx) intersect with a certian visual. So you would have to define a geometry or a list of points that more or less closely match the bounds of your 2nd visual.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`Rect.IntersectsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.intersectswith.aspx) method

Comment: For WinRT Metro apps, there is also Rect.Intersect that will give an empty rectangle if there is no intersection, and an actual result when there is.

Comment: Tks Den! I was looking for this for WinRT.