# how to compare the bounds of wpf rectangles xaml element

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a little platforming game and I want to compare the bounds of one player rectangle with many rectangle elements that are my platforms. I know in WinForms I can just use a PictureBox `.bounds.intersectswith()` method.

in my xaml I define my controls like this inside a gridpane called program.

```
 <Rectangle Name="player" Tag="player"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="61" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Canvas.Top="332" Canvas.Left="25">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="player.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle Tag="platform"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="82" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Canvas.Top="398">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="purplebrick.png"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

and then I want to compare the bounds of the player with the about 50 platforms.

```
 foreach (Rectangle x in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(program))
        {
            if (x is Rectangle && x.Tag.ToString() == "platform")
            { 
                 if(player.intersectswiht(x) // problem area
```

iv been using this question [Bounds.Intersect for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003201/bounds-intersect-for-wpf) as a reference but do I need to name every rectangle element and create an actual reference to be able to use its intersect with function?

or should I just compare every elements dimensions (canvas.top ect)but that would only give me the edges value not a range for if they overlap correct?

Comment: When you create the platform rectangles, you could add them to a `List<Rectangle>` and just compare against that, but you aren't showing how you are creating them... Are you really doing each one in XAML? Or are you loading a level and creating it in code?

Comment: im doing each one in XAML currently is that a bad decision?

Comment: You can do it that way, but really seems tedious. The issue though is that the WPF `Rectangle` is a visual control, unlike the GDI `Rectangle` which is a layout/helper class, which is closer to [`System.Windows.Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx) for WPF. Take a look at [`Rect.IntersectsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.intersectswith.aspx)

Comment: rect.intersectswith is the function I was planning on using but is the only way to access it to have distinct rectangle references instead of my many xaml rectangles with a tag? Do i need to replace them with a nonvisual control rectangle? Id like to hack together a way just using the visual controls

Comment: If you loop through your rectangles and add them to a `List<Rectangle> myPlatforms` (or something similiar) you can do this in code: `if myPlatforms.Any(p => IntersectsRect(player, p))) { ... }` and then the function `IntersectsRect` takes the `player` and `p` (platform) rectangle and uses `Rect.IntersectsWith` returning true if it does, that would work, if you get what I'm pushing at...

Comment: ok that was an option i was debating just making a rectangle list like that. Maybe im just not thinking straight but I cant think of how you would assign the visual control to the rectangle list tho. something like `foreach (Rectangle x in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(program)){
 myplatforms.add(new rectangle(x)) }` or for the new rectangle function have to assign every value doing of the visual control? im not sure what the equivalent coordinates would be

Comment: That is the problem with using WPF for this, it can change depending on DPI or screen resolution. Really you should be using something designed to do this, like [Unity3d Platformer](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/creating-basic-platformer-game)

Comment: yeah I'm very much recognizing that. is there any solution you could think of that could get this platformer running? just compare the platforms canvas.topproperty possibly?

Comment: Iv got this mostly working but how would I distinguish between what platform in the myPlatforms is the player intersecting with?